# Testing an uninstalled outlet

Tags: wiring, gfci, testing

Is there some way to test an outlet to see if it's good and works without going through all the effort of installing it, like maybe with DC from a battery so that the LED lights? That may not be a *true* indicator, I realize, as the unit could be good, but the LED burned out, but it's a start, yeah?

Thanks.

Comment: What failure condition are you trying to catch? For basic conductivity, your multimeter should have a continuity test function if you just want to check that the terminal screws are conducting to the two receptacle.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with just things around the house already, no "specialized" equipment like multimeters, etc. If not. I'll try taking it to Home Depot of HFT tomorrow.

Comment: Normal receptacles, at least in the US, don't have LEDs. That makes me think "GFCI indicator light". There is no practical way to test that without 120V AC power, and the easiest way to do that is to install it. If it was previously installed and had problems then replacement will be more like $10 than $2 because of the GFCI, but as a key human safety system replacement is the way to go.

Comment: Testing any electrical items should be done with the proper equipment. You can check the brass and silver screws to see if they're scratched and also check the mating surfaces. this might give you an indication if the outlet's been previously installed.

Answer (score 4):

Easy as pie, it's a 2-step diagnostic process.

1. Throw it in the trash.
2. Buy another one for $2.50.  Or 60 cents if you like the cheapies.

Pressing onward with a receptacle that is in any way suspect is not worth your time.

Answer (score 1):

An outlet is a very simple device electrically.  An ohmmeter will verify that the front terminals (where the plug mates with it) and the screw terminals in the rear (where the wires attach) are connected. If that is OK and a physical inspection of the outlet shows no cracks or corrosion, then it is almost certain that the outlet is OK.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your little tests is that the outlet can/will react differently with the higher voltage and current that it's designed for. Outlets usually fail because the "jaws" become weak and don't grasp the plug tight enough. The other reason for failure is how they are wired. Using the back stabs instead of hooking the wires on the terminal screws can cause poor connections and failure of the outlet. Outlets are very inexpensive and easy to install. Just pick one up and install it. Remember to turn off the power before doing any work and take a few pictures before you disconnect anything so you can post them if you run into problems.. Good luck

Comment: "Outlets are very inexpensive and easy to install." So you won't mind treating me to one, huh? Thanks! But yeah, I can install just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not worried about internal electrical connectivity, and new outlets are basically guaranteed to work; don't bother testing them. Two tests I would suggest on old outlets that aren't installed for some reason:

1) Check for scorch marks around the back connectors, or any other physical damage.

2) Plug a cord in, and see if it has a tendency to "flop" out, leaving exposed metal.